# Mysql doesn't update for some people in my system

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $redirect_link = false;
        $model = new Page();
        $user_ip = $model->get_client_ip_server();
        $geoData = $model->geoCheckIP($user_ip);

        $user_id = CAuth::getLoggedId();
        $user_name = CAuth::getLoggedName();
        $user_email = CAuth::getLoggedEmail();
        $user_country = $geoData['country'];

        //=====================Settings===========================//
        $vote_type = 'xTreamtop';
        $amount = 3;
        $Link = 'http://www.xtremetop100.com/in.php?site=1132356694';
        //========================================================//

        $current_time = time();
        $addTodb = false;
        $sendCubi = false;
        $getRank = $model->getVUID($user_name, $vote_type);
        $getUNMCount = $model->getCount('mw_vote', 'user="'.$user_name.'" AND type="'.$vote_type.'"');
        $getCIPCount = $model->getCount('mw_vote', 'ip="'.$user_ip.'" AND type="'.$vote_type.'"');

        if ($getUNMCount > 1) {
            if ($getCIPCount > 1) 
            {
                $unData = $model->getMID($user_name, $vote_type);
                $ipData = $model->getMIP($user_ip, $vote_type);
                $iDate = $ipData['date'];
                $uDate = $unData['date'];
                if ($iDate > $uDate){
                    $latestVote = $ipData;
                }else {
                    $latestVote = $unData;
            }
            }else 
            {
                $latestVote = $model->getMID($user_name, $vote_type);
            }
        }else {
            if ($getCIPCount > 1) 
            {
                $latestVote = $model->getMIP($user_ip, $vote_type);
            }else 
            {
                $getVUID = $model->getVUID($user_name, $vote_type);
                $getVCIP = $model->getVCIP($user_ip, $vote_type);
                $vuidDate = $getVUID['date'];
                $vcipDate = $getVCIP['date'];
                if ($vuidDate > $vcipDate){
                    $latestVote = $getVUID;
                }else {
                    $latestVote = $getVCIP;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($latestVote['rank'] == 0 or empty($latestVote['rank']))
        {
            $addTodb = true;
        }

        if ($addTodb == false) {
            $timeCalc = $current_time - $latestVote['date'];
            if ($timeCalc < 21600) {
                $msg = 'Hello '.$user_name.' you have already voted with this account ('.$user_name.') or IP ('.$user_ip.')  in the last 6hrs, Please wait '.date('h', $timeCalc).' hours and '.date('i', $timeCalc).'minutes! <br />Last voted on: '.date('M d\, h:i:s A', $latestVote['date']).'';
                header('refresh: 5; url=vote');
            }else{
                $update = $model->updateVote(array(
                        'uid' => $user_id,
                        'user' => $user_name,
                        'email' => $user_email,
                        'country' => $user_country,
                        'ip' => $user_ip,
                        'date' => $current_time,
                        'rank' => $getRank['rank']+1,
                        'cubi' => $getRank['cubi']+$amount,
                ), 'uid="'.$user_id.'" AND type="'.$vote_type.'"');

                if (!$update){
                    $msg = 'Fail to Update voting database.';
                    header('refresh: 5; url=vote');
                }else{
                    $sendCubi = true;
                }
            }
        }else {
            $insert = $model->addVote(array(
                        'uid' => $user_id,
                        'user' => $user_name,
                        'email' => $user_email,
                        'country' => $user_country,
                        'ip' => $user_ip,
                        'date' => $current_time,
                        'type' => $vote_type,
                        'rank' => '1',
                        'cubi' => $amount,
                    ));
            if ($insert){
                $sendCubi = true;
            }else{
                $msg = 'Fail to insert voting database.';
                header('refresh: 5; url=vote');
            }

        }

        if ($sendCubi) {
            $addCash = $model->addCubi($user_id, $amount);
            if ($addCash){
                $model->addLog(array(
                    'user' => $user_id,
                    'product' => base64_encode('Voted for XtremeTop100.com'),
                    'event' => 'vote',
                    'wallet' => $amount,
                    'type' => 'ingame',
                ));

                $getPoints = $model->getPoints($user_name);
                if (empty($getPoints)){
                    $addPoints = true;
                }else{
                    $addPoints = false;
                }

                if ($addPoints){
                    $model->addPoints(array(
                        'username' => $user_name,
                        'cubi' => $amount,
                        'points' => '1',
                    ));
                }else{
                    $model->updatePoints(array(
                        'username' => $user_name,
                        'cubi' => $getPoints['cubi']+$amount,
                        'points' => $getPoints['points']+1,
                    ), 'username="'.$user_name.'"');
                }

                $msg = 'Added cubi to the account';
                header('Location: '.$Link.'');
            }else{
                $msg = 'Please make post on forum saying that you could receive gold after vote';
            }

        }
        $this->view->render('page/xtreamtop');
```

Here is my voting sytem, for some reason some people keep voting. It doesn't update the database or insert into the database, only for some people it's doing it correctly. I don't see any mistake in this code. Please check this script and let me know how to stop people from cheating my system.

Comment: And we are supposed to bench test all that code for you are we?

Comment: nah im not asking to test all code for me. just give me a idea the way make a vote system that people can vote every 6 hours without cheat. i need someone show me the path. so i can go on the way.

Comment: The first thing you could do is add some additional logging and specify the logged in user for each log entry to see how the failed votes differ from succesful ones.

Comment: i did it and i found timestamp doesn't update on mysql.